# CSS Tooltip responsive without Javascript

Tags: css, tooltip, responsive

I would like to integrate the W3-Tooltip in my project. It works fine on normal screens, but fails on mobile phones. The example is here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip_arrow_left

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -5px;
  left: 110%;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<h2>Right Tooltip w/ Left Arrow</h2>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When making the screen smaller, the tooltip will stay where it is and a scroll bar will appear.

I would like to have a css-solution, where the tooltip will be positioned differently on small screens. My idea is to have

- left and width: relative to screen
- top: relative to parent object (the underlined keyword)

Then the tooltip could fill the screen from left to right border but stay under the keyword.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this positioning issue? I would prefer a solution without javascript, but if it is not possible without, then it would also be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Use a media query to position the tooltip differently on a smaller screen:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { /* adjust max-width for the screen-size you want */
    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
    width: 120px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    margin-top: 10px; /* adjust this if needed */
  }

  .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -9px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you also have an idea how to make the tooltip begin at the left side of the screen and full width? So it would fill the screen completely from left to right.

Comment: @HansMeyer I do not think this is possible without the parent (the .tooltip) having a fixed width. The position of the .tooltiptext is absolute, so it depends on the relative parent. You could use a wrapper element and two tooltips instead like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Sirence/5bf9ohk2/23/ But I do not think there is another solution (besides fixed width, like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561293/css-tooltip-responsive-without-javascript/59562103#59562103)